# Web Server access via second interface

Tags: iptables, network-interface, routing, webserver, nat

I’m trying to access a Web Service (port 8080) on my Raspberry Pi via both of the following interfaces (which have static IPs):

- Ethernet (eth0, 172.22.0.99, connected to a Netgear router).
- Wi-Fi (wlan0, 172.24.1.1, providing an Access Point).

Currently, I can only access the web service if I connect to eth0 and gain an IP address 172.22.0.x.

If I connect to the Wi-Fi Access Point on wlan0 then I correctly acquire an IP Address 172.24.1.x, hence SSH works, but the web service is inaccessible (both http://172.22.0.99:8080 and http://172.24.1.1:8080).

I’ve been testing the above using a Windows 10 laptop. The actual problem is that I have a number of Arduinos which can connect to the Pi’s Wi-Fi Access Point (wlan0), but cannot then access the Pi’s Web Service. Hence instead I’m currently having to connect them via the Netgear router, and hence the Pi’s eth0. This is what I’m trying to avoid.

Aside: the Pi is also running:

- OpenVPN, hence eth0 is bridged (br0, tap0).
- A Wi-Fi sniffer (wlan1alfa, renameX).
- 172.22.0.100/102/106/113 examples of a working Arduinos

Various outputs :

**Windows 10 laptop when connected to the Pi’s Wi-Fi Access Point:**

```
ipconfig (on laptop 172.24.1.42):
```

> Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:
>
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
>
> Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::7489:b292:4e73:cbfd%2
>
> IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . :172.24.1.42
>
> Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
>
> Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.24.1.1

http://172.22.0.99:8080/ (on laptop 172.24.1.42)

```
Unable to connect

Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 172.22.0.99.

The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.

If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.

If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

http://172.24.1.1:8080/ (on laptop 172.24.1.42)

```
The connection has timed out

The server at 172.24.1.1 is taking too long to respond.

The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.

If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.

If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

**Pi:**

$ ifconfig

```
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 82:85:54:54:e1:8c
          inet addr:172.22.0.99  Bcast:172.22.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ba27:ebff:fe1a:16a3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1150213 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:431995 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:200587924 (191.2 MiB)  TX bytes:137714386 (131.3 MiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:1a:16:a3
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1150375 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:449400 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:200603903 (191.3 MiB)  TX bytes:143711369 (137.0 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1128130 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1128130 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:129944607 (123.9 MiB)  TX bytes:129944607 (123.9 MiB)

rename7   Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-C0-CA-8F-F8-1D-30-30-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2753461 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:328484228 (313.2 MiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

tap0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 82:85:54:54:e1:8c
          inet6 addr: fe80::8085:54ff:fe54:e18c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:644390 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:135759131 (129.4 MiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:4f:43:f6
          inet addr:172.24.1.1  Bcast:172.24.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::f446:4155:5d19:860a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:479547 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:488461 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:30867423 (29.4 MiB)  TX bytes:40144827 (38.2 MiB)
```

$ ip route

```
default via 172.22.0.1 dev br0  metric 205
default via 172.24.1.1 dev wlan0  metric 303
172.22.0.0/16 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.22.0.99  metric 205
172.24.1.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.24.1.1  metric 303
```

$ ip addr show

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:1a:16:a3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:4f:43:f6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.24.1.1/24 brd 172.24.1.255 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::f446:4155:5d19:860a/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: wlan1alfa: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:c0:ca:8f:f8:1d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 82:85:54:54:e1:8c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.22.0.99/16 brd 172.22.255.255 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe1a:16a3/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: tap0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/ether 82:85:54:54:e1:8c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::8085:54ff:fe54:e18c/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: rename7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ieee802.11/radiotap 00:c0:ca:8f:f8:1d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

iptables:

```
# Add a masquerade for outbound traffic on eth0
iptables -t nat -A  POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

..
echo "  # Forward WLAN to Eth, and back (note: incoming initiated on WLAN do not get to LAN)"

sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j FORWARD_LOG_ACCEPT -m comment --comment Accept_FORWARD_WLAN0_to_Eth0 

sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j FORWARD_LOG_ACCEPT -m comment --comment Accept_FORWARD_Eth0_backTo_WLAN0

sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -j FORWARD_LOG_ACCEPT -m comment --comment Accept_FORWARD_eth0_to_wlan0

sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j FORWARD_LOG_ACCEPT -m comment --comment Accept_FORWARD_wlan0_to_eth0
```

$ tail /var/log/messages from iptables (with everything being logged whether Accepted or Dropped):

trying http://172.22.0.99:8080 :

```
•   Feb 18 13:23:25 shep kernel: [1630978.112563] IPTables-Accepted-I: IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=b8:27:eb:4f:43:f6:60:14:b3:74:61:cf:08:00 SRC=172.24.1.42 (laptop) DST=172.22.0.99 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=26841 PROTO=TCP SPT=51634 DPT=22 WINDOW=66 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
•   Feb 18 13:23:37 shep kernel: [1630990.317785] IPTables-Accepted-I: IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=b8:27:eb:4f:43:f6:60:14:b3:74:61:cf:08:00 SRC=172.24.1.42 (laptop) DST=172.22.0.99 LEN=104 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=26843 PROTO=TCP SPT=51634 DPT=22 WINDOW=68 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
•   Feb 18 13:23:37 shep kernel: [1630990.318185] IPTables-Accepted-O: IN= OUT=wlan0 SRC=172.22.0.99 DST=172.24.1.42 (laptop) LEN=104 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=54479 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=22 DPT=51634 WINDOW=424 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
•   Feb 18 13:23:49 shep kernel: [1631002.193203] IPTables-Accepted-I: IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=b8:27:eb:4f:43:f6:60:14:b3:74:61:cf:08:00 SRC=172.24.1.42 (laptop) DST=172.22.0.99 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=26851 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51642 DPT=80 WINDOW=17520 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
•   Feb 18 13:23:49 shep kernel: [1631002.193337] IPTables-Accepted-O: IN= OUT=wlan0 SRC=172.22.0.99 DST=172.24.1.42 (laptop) LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=51503 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=51642 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 ACK RST URGP=0
•   Feb 18 13:24:01 shep kernel: [1631014.835337] IPTables-Accepted-O: IN= OUT=lo SRC=172.22.0.99 DST=172.22.0.99 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=23677 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=60692 DPT=8080 WINDOW=43690 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
•   Feb 18 13:24:01 shep kernel: [1631014.835409] IPTables-Accepted-I: IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=172.22.0.99 DST=172.22.0.99 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=23677 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=60692 DPT=8080 WINDOW=43690 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
•   Feb 18 13:24:27 shep kernel: [1631039.962078] IPTables-Accepted-I: IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=b8:27:eb:4f:43:f6:60:14:b3:74:61:cf:08:00 SRC=172.24.1.42 (laptop) DST=172.22.0.99 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=26874 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51648 DPT=80 WINDOW=17520 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
•   Feb 18 13:24:27 shep kernel: [1631039.962176] IPTables-Accepted-O: IN= OUT=wlan0 SRC=172.22.0.99 DST=172.24.1.42 (laptop) LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=53485 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=51648 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 ACK RST URGP=0
•   Feb 18 13:24:37 shep kernel: [1631050.042812] IPTables-Accepted-O: IN= OUT=br0 SRC=172.22.0.99 DST=172.22.0.113 LEN=520 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=55862 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=8080 DPT=50211 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
•   Feb 18 13:24:37 shep kernel: [1631050.065256] IPTables-Accepted-I: IN=br0 OUT= MAC=82:85:54:54:e1:8c:ec:fa:bc:14:3f:6e:08:00 SRC=172.22.0.113 (Arduino) DST=172.22.0.99 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=31426 PROTO=TCP SPT=50211 DPT=8080 WINDOW=1200 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
•   Feb 18 13:24:49 shep kernel: [1631062.130744] IPTables-Accepted-I: IN=br0 OUT= MAC=82:85:54:54:e1:8c:ec:fa:bc:14:3f:6e:08:00 SRC=172.22.0.113 (Arduino) DST=172.22.0.99 LEN=150 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=31430 PROTO=TCP SPT=50211 DPT=8080 WINDOW=1672 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
•   Feb 18 13:24:49 shep kernel: [1631062.131706] IPTables-Accepted-O: IN= OUT=br0 SRC=172.22.0.99 DST=172.22.0.113 LEN=519 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=55865 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=8080 DPT=50211 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
•   Feb 18 13:25:01 shep kernel: [1631074.255485] IPTables-Accepted-I: IN=br0 OUT= MAC=82:85:54:54:e1:8c:ec:fa:bc:14:3f:6e:08:00 SRC=172.22.0.113 (Arduino) DST=172.22.0.99 LEN=165 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=31435 PROTO=TCP SPT=50211 DPT=8080 WINDOW=1645 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
•   Feb 18 13:25:01 shep kernel: [1631074.301286] IPTables-Accepted-O: IN= OUT=br0 SRC=172.22.0.99 DST=172.22.0.113 (Arduino) LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=55867 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=8080 DPT=50211 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
```

trying http://172.24.1.1:8080 :

```
•   Feb 18 15:14:15 shep kernel: [1637627.961592] IPTables-Accepted-I: IN=br0 OUT= MAC=82:85:54:54:e1:8c:18:fe:34:d2:92:d6:08:00 SRC=172.22.0.102 (Arduino 2) DST=172.22.0.99 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=72 PROTO=TCP SPT=52001 DPT=8080 WINDOW=1875 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0
•   Feb 18 15:14:15 shep kernel: [1637627.961831] IPTables-Accepted-O: IN= OUT=br0 SRC=172.22.0.99 DST=172.22.0.102 (Arduino 2) LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=11122 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=8080 DPT=52001 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0
•   Feb 18 15:14:25 shep kernel: [1637638.193698] IPTables-Accepted-I: IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=b8:27:eb:4f:43:f6:5c:cf:7f:3c:59:86:08:00 SRC=172.24.1.106 (Arduino 3) DST=172.22.0.99 LEN=81 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=16314 PROTO=TCP SPT=49154 DPT=1883 WINDOW=1884 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
•   Feb 18 15:14:25 shep kernel: [1637638.194012] IPTables-Accepted-O: IN= OUT=lo SRC=172.22.0.99 DST=172.22.0.99 LEN=93 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=3867 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=1883 DPT=50392 WINDOW=6231 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
•   Feb 18 15:14:35 shep kernel: [1637648.508430] IPTables-Accepted-I: IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=b8:27:eb:4f:43:f6:60:14:b3:74:61:cf:08:00 SRC=172.24.1.42 (laptop) DST=172.22.0.99 LEN=104 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=27282 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=52149 DPT=22 WINDOW=64 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
•   Feb 18 15:14:35 shep kernel: [1637648.508521] IPTables-Accepted-O: IN= OUT=wlan0 SRC=172.22.0.99 DST=172.24.1.42 (laptop) LEN=40 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=31818 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=22 DPT=52149 WINDOW=269 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
•   Feb 18 15:14:48 shep kernel: [1637661.183931] IPTables-Accepted-I: IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=b8:27:eb:4f:43:f6:60:14:b3:74:61:cf:08:00 SRC=172.24.1.42 (laptop) DST=172.22.0.99 LEN=120 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=27329 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=52149 DPT=22 WINDOW=68 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
•   Feb 18 15:14:48 shep kernel: [1637661.187210] IPTables-Accepted-O: IN= OUT=wlan0 SRC=172.22.0.99 DST=172.24.1.42 LEN=1500 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=31852 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=22 DPT=52149 WINDOW=269 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
•   Feb 18 15:14:58 shep kernel: [1637671.438928] IPTables-Accepted-I: IN=br0 OUT= MAC=82:85:54:54:e1:8c:18:fe:34:d2:96:51:08:00 SRC=172.22.0.100 (Arduino 4) DST=172.22.0.99 LEN=150 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=1463 PROTO=TCP SPT=52080 DPT=8080 WINDOW=1680 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
•   Feb 18 15:14:58 shep kernel: [1637671.440119] IPTables-Accepted-O: IN= OUT=br0 SRC=172.22.0.99 DST=172.22.0.100 (Arduino 4) LEN=520 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=60505 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=8080 DPT=52080 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
```

Edit 1 (but see Edit 2). The Web Service is 'domoticz':

```
$ sudo netstat -taupen | grep LISTEN

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          15295       1847/smbd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5901            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       11927       1437/Xtightvnc
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       11924       1437/Xtightvnc
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          14462       1154/dnsmasq
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          14453       1143/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1880            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       15768       716/node-red
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1883            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          11708       903/mosquitto
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          15294       1847/smbd
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          15293       1847/smbd
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      1000       4902627     25249/domoticz
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          14464       1154/dnsmasq
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          14455       1143/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::1883                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          11709       903/mosquitto
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          15292       1847/smbd
tcp6       0      0 :::6144                 :::*                    LISTEN      1000       4902635     25249/domoticz
```

$ netstat -ntl

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5901            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6001            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1880            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1883            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::1883                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::6144                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

Edit 2: Following a configuration change, the Domoticz Web Server is now listening on 0.0.0.0:8080, but still fails as above.

> $ sudo netstat -taupen | grep domoticz
>
> ```
> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1000       21943078    27425/domoticz   <<---
> tcp        0      0 172.22.0.99:8080        172.22.0.102:52060      ESTABLISHED 1000       21949101    27425/domoticz
> tcp        0      0 172.22.0.99:8080        172.22.0.100:52135      ESTABLISHED 1000       21949100    27425/domoticz
> tcp        0      0 172.22.0.99:58528       172.22.0.99:1883        ESTABLISHED 1000       21946463    27425/domoticz
> tcp6       0      0 :::6144                 :::*                    LISTEN      1000       21943086    27425/domoticz
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! I was only doing the following single flush command:

```
sudo iptables -F
```

Hence specifically I wasn't flushing all of the iptables rules, eg. the NAT.

So I had this mess of PREROUTING & POSTROUTING duplicates:

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http-alt to:192.168.0.99:8080
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http-alt to:192.168.0.99:8080
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http-alt to:192.168.0.99:8080
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http-alt to:192.168.0.99:8080
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http-alt to:192.168.0.99:8080
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http-alt to:192.168.0.99:8080
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http-alt to:192.168.0.99:8080
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http-alt to:172.22.0.99:8080
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http-alt to:172.22.0.99:8080
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http-alt to:172.22.0.99:8080
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http-alt to:172.22.0.99:8080
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http-alt to:172.22.0.99:8080

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Once I started using the following before creating my rules it worked (no other change):

```
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -X
sudo iptables -t nat -F
sudo iptables -t nat -X
sudo iptables -t mangle -F
sudo iptables -t mangle -X

sudo ipset flush
sudo ipset destroy
sudo ipset list
```

Apparently I should also do:

```
sudo iptables -t raw -F 
sudo iptables -t raw -X
```

Now I have:

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http-alt to:172.22.0.99:8080

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

So now if I connect to the Pi's Wireless Access Point on 172.24.1.1 (wlan0) and get IP address 172.24.1.x I can access the Domoticz Web Server on the Pi via http://172.24.1.1:8080, which is what I want.

It was previously the case that I had to go via a separate router (172.22.0.1), get IP address 172.22.0.x, and access the Pi via eth0: http://172.22.0.99:8080.